# Unity screwing up meshes when parenting objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, primitive

Pictures are self explanatory:
[image: Cube and cylinder, everything works]

[image: Cube and cylinder, cylinder parented to cube.]

Can anyone help me ? How can i parent objects without having them to distort that way ?
Tried resetting transform values to default in cylinder properties, but it is still distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your child object is inheriting the scale of the parent object. The way to fix that is to scale the child object by values that will multiply with appropriate parent Game Object's scale values to return the child game object to a scale of 1 1 1.

Example:

Parent Game Object has a scale of 2  5  .5 and I want the child Game Object to have a scale of 1 1 1. I set the child Game Object to a scale of .5  .2  2

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, helped. Thanks. Also, i managed to pair them in another way ( kind of ) without having them to distort. Made an empty game object and parentet them to it.

Comment: That would be the other way to do it. Unity is "supposed" to automatically do what I suggested to do, but poop happens at times.